# Filter elements in descending order

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I want to solve the following problem efficiently:

Given a list of pairs (value, data), I want to remove all the pairs so that the resulting list has the value property of its elements sorted. That is, for example:

```
l = { {6, data1}, {8, data2}, {4, data3}, {5, data4}, {6, data5}, {0, data6}, {1, data7}}
```

`MyFilter[l]` should return

```
{{6, data1}, {4, data3}, {0, data6}}
```

How can I achieve this efficiently? Should I try a Reap & Sow based approach? I am still not sure how to use them correctly (I am new to functional programming).

Comment: `Delete[l, Position[Sign[Differences[l[[All, 1]]]], 1] + 1]`?

Comment: @J.M. won't work with `{{6, data1}, {8, data2}, {7, data3},...`

Comment: Can we assume that you want to always take the first available element? That is, `{{6, data1}, {5, data4}, {1, data7}}` also satisfies "the resulting list has the value property of its elements sorted", but I assume it's _not_ a valid answer.

Comment: @aardvark2012 correct, you always have to take the first available element. Thanks for clarifying that, I had not though about it.

Comment: Three answers (plus one deleted) and only one upvote?!  If it's worth four answers, it surely must be worth a couple of upvotes too! (+1 so now you have 2).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Solution 1

A solution using `Sow` and `Reap`:

```
Reap[
  Module[
   {c = Infinity},
   Scan[
    If[#[[1]] < c, c = #[[1]]; Sow@#] &,
    l
    ]
   ]
  ][[2, 1]]
```

This one keeps track of the current maximum through the variable `c`, and uses `Sow` and `Reap` to collect the data.

## Solution 2

Another one, this time without `Module`:

```
Reap[
  MapThread[
   If[#1[[1]] == #2, Sow@#1] &,
   {
    l,
    Rest@FoldList[Min[#, #2[[1]]] &, Infinity, l]
    }
   ]
  ][[2, 1]]
```

This one creates a list of the current minimum at each position using [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html), and uses this list together with the original one in [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html)

## Solution 3

And a third, based on the previous one:

```
Select[
  {
    l,
    Rest@FoldList[Min[#, #2[[1]]] &, Infinity, l]
    }\[Transpose]
  , Apply[#1[[1]] == #2 &]
  ][[All, 1]]
```

Pretty similar to the previous one, but we put the lists together using `Transpose{l1,l2}`, and filter using [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html)

## Solution 4

```
Reap[
  Fold[
   If[#1 > #2[[1]], Sow@#2; #2[[1]], #1] &,
   Infinity,
   l
   ]
  ][[2, 1]]
```

This is very similar to the first one, but instead of a local variable `c`, this one uses [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) to pass the current minimum along.

## Timings

I attempted to perform some benchmarking, using randomly generated data:

```
data[n_] := Table[{RandomInteger[n], Indexed[data, i]}, {i, n}]
```

The results are the following:
[image]

Answer (score 8):

This is one rather compact way:

```
numbers = l[[All, 1]]
(* {6, 8, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1} *)

steps = FoldList[Min, numbers]
(* {6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0} *)

Pick[l, steps - numbers, 0]
(* {{6, data1}, {4, data3}, {0, data6}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

This method works by recursively selecting elements that are less than their predecessor.

```
refine[l_] := Module[{tl = {Infinity}~Join~Transpose[l][[1]]},
  Pick[l, Order @@@ Partition[tl, 2, 1], -1]
  ]
myFilter = FixedPoint[refine, #] &
```

The example from the question:

```
l = {{6, data1}, {8, data2}, {4, data3}, {5, data4}, {6, data5}, {0, data6}, {1, data7}};
myFilter[l]

(* {{6, data1}, {4, data3}, {0, data6}} *)
```

Another example:

```
l = {{6, data1}, {8, data2}, {7, data3}, {5, data4}, {6, data5}, {0, data6}, {1, data7}};
myFilter[l]

(* {{6, data1}, {5, data4}, {0, data6}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Fold[If[Min[#1[[All, 1]]] > #2[[1]], Append[#1, #2], #1] &, {l[[1]]}, 
 Rest@l]
```